# Last row as cuttoff in ListView Xamarin forms

Tags: forms, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning xamarin forms and so far I have been able to advance with the help of the forum and the Internet, but I am having a problem that I can not solve.
In summary, I have a Listview that shows a data collection and I use mvvm.
The problem is that when viewing it on the mobile, the last row is cut off and the buttons at the bottom of the page are not displayed either.
I have read several topics and have tried several things, but none works.
PS: I can not establish a fixed height, it has to be dynamic, depending on the size of the data.

```
<StackLayout Style = "{StaticResource whiteBody}">
            <FlexLayout Direction = "Column" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
                <Grid VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height = "Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height = "Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height = "Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height = "Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height = "*" />
                    </ Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width = "Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width = "*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "0" Grid.ColumnSpan = "2" Style = "{StaticResource redBar}">
                        <Label Style = "{StaticResource whiteText}" Text = "OFFER FINDER" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand"
                                AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "True"
                                AutomationProperties.HelpText = "My offers"
                                AutomationProperties.Name = "My offers" />
                        <Label Style = "{StaticResource whiteText}" Text = "MENU" x: Name = "menuLink" HorizontalOptions = "EndAndExpand"
                                AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "True"
                                AutomationProperties.HelpText = "Back to menu"
                                AutomationProperties.Name = "Menu">
                            <! - <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command = "{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter = "{x: Local Type: MenuView}"
                                        NumberOfTapsRequired = "1" />
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers> ->
                        </ Label>
                    </ StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "1" Grid.ColumnSpan = "2" Style = "{StaticResource backSave}">
                        <Label Style = "{StaticResource redText}" Text = "Return" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand"
                                AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "True"
                                AutomationProperties.HelpText = "Back to the offers search"
                                AutomationProperties.Name = "Back to search engine" />
                        <Label Style = "{StaticResource redText}" Text = "Save search" x: Name = "saveSearch" HorizontalOptions = "End"
                                AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "True"
                                AutomationProperties.HelpText = "Save search"
                                AutomationProperties.Name = "Save search">
                            <! - <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command = "{Binding NavigateCommand}" CommandParameter = "{x: Local Type: MenuView}"
                                        NumberOfTapsRequired = "1" />
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers> ->
                        </ Label>
                    </ StackLayout>
                    <FlexLayout Direction = "Column" Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "2" Grid.ColumnSpan = "2" HeightRequest = "1">
                        <BoxView Style = "{StaticResource lineHorz}" AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "False" />
                    </ FlexLayout>
                    <! - Square content ->
                        <ListView Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "3" Grid.ColumnSpan = "2" HasUnevenRows = "True" ItemsSource = "{Binding DealsList}"
                                   x: Name = "OffersListView" SeparatorVisibility = "Default" HeightRequest = "1000">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout Style = "{StaticResource resultStack}" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
                                            <StackLayout x: Name = "stackFavorites" Style = "{StaticResource favsStack}">
                                                <BoxView BackgroundColor = "Gray" HorizontalOptions = "Start" VerticalOptions = "Center"
                                                     HeightRequest = "45" WidthRequest = "45" Margin = "25,0,0,0"
                                                    AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "False" />
                                                <Label Text = "{Binding stateFav}" VerticalOptions = "Center" Margin = "5"> </ Label>
                                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command = "{Binding changeFav}" NumberOfTapsRequired = "1" />
                                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the  result like following GIF??(I do not know what is your styles of every control, so i delete it)

[image]

If you want to achieve that, Pease wrap a `ScrollView` outside the `stacklayout` like following code.( I delete the height of `listview`, it can be adjusted height by the content)

```
    <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <FlexLayout  Direction = "Column" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
        <Grid VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
            <!--5 行 2列 -->

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackLayout Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "0" Grid.ColumnSpan = "2">
                <Label  Text = "OFFER FINDER" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand"
                            AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "True"
                            AutomationProperties.HelpText = "My offers"
                            AutomationProperties.Name = "My offers" />
                <Label  Text = "MENU" x:Name = "menuLink" HorizontalOptions = "EndAndExpand"
                            AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "True"
                            AutomationProperties.HelpText = "Back to menu"
                            AutomationProperties.Name = "Menu">

                </Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "1" Grid.ColumnSpan = "2" >
                <Label  Text = "Return" HorizontalOptions = "StartAndExpand"
                            AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "True"
                            AutomationProperties.HelpText = "Back to the offers search"
                            AutomationProperties.Name = "Back to search engine" />
                <Label  Text = "Save search" x:Name = "saveSearch" HorizontalOptions = "End"
                            AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "True"
                            AutomationProperties.HelpText = "Save search"
                            AutomationProperties.Name = "Save search">

                </Label>
            </StackLayout>

            <FlexLayout Direction = "Column" Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "2" Grid.ColumnSpan = "2" HeightRequest = "1">
                <BoxView  AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "False" />
            </FlexLayout>
            <!-- Square content -->
            <ListView Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "3" Grid.ColumnSpan = "2" HasUnevenRows = "True" 
                               x:Name = "OffersListView" SeparatorVisibility = "Default" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout  VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
                                <StackLayout x:Name = "stackFavorites" >
                                    <BoxView BackgroundColor = "Gray" HorizontalOptions = "Start" VerticalOptions = "Center"
                                                 HeightRequest = "45" WidthRequest = "45" Margin = "25,0,0,0"
                                                AutomationProperties.IsInAccessibleTree = "False" />
                                    <Label Text = "{Binding stateFav}" VerticalOptions = "Center" Margin = "5"></Label>
                                    <!--    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command = "{Binding changeFav}" NumberOfTapsRequired = "1" />
                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers> -->
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <StackLayout Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "4" Grid.ColumnSpan = "2" >


                <Grid VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" >
                    <!--5 行 2列 -->

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button  Text="Button1" Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "0" />
                    <Button  Text="Button2"  Grid.Column = "1" Grid.Row = "0" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </FlexLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I had forgotten that HeightRequest, it was just a test to see how it worked.
Thank you very much, it has been fixed.
It hurts me to know that it was just that.

Comment: Are there any updates for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.